Append/Fill incremental tar backup with volume size
I am backing up incremental data onto BD-R with 23866 MiB.
The space of CD should be used as much, so I set the volume size as 3977 MiB.
The last backup is as this.
ar1.tar.075 - 3977 M
ar1.tar.076 - 3977 M
ar1.tar.077 - 1717 M

Then I tried this command.
$ cp ar1.snar ar2.snar
$ cp ar1.tar.077 ar2.tar.000

$ tar -rv -L 3977M -g ar2.snar -C /data --file=ar2.tar.{000..999} .

The printed file list seems too many than expected.
What I get is.
ar2.tar.000 - 5694 M (1717 + 3977)
ar2.tar.001 - 3977 M
ar2.tar.002 - 3977 M

The size is far bigger than expected. The first volume is unusable on CD.
It seems that incremental file list not work.
Is there a way to achieve any of below, with incremental file list, which may include file deletion record?

Fill the last tar volume, continuing previous backup.
Control the first volume size.
Concentrate tar with various size, to new tar with same volume size.

